# Reshape input data for LSTM autoencoder

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm

I used to use `model.add(Reshape())` from Keras but for some reason the same code that worked before does not work now. I am trying to reshape the input for LSTM without reshaping the data prior; without using `np.reshape` command.
My code is:

```
def model_lstm_ae ():
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(Reshape((1,X_train_.shape[1])))
    model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu', 
                   input_shape=(1,X_train_.shape[1]), return_sequences=True))

    model.add(LSTM(64, activation='relu', 
                   return_sequences=False))

    model.add(RepeatVector(timesteps))

    model.add(LSTM(64, activation='relu', 
                   return_sequences=True))

    model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu', 
                   return_sequences=False))

    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))

    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', 
                  optimizer=k.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-4, amsgrad=True))

    return model

model_lstm_ae = KerasRegressor(build_fn=model_lstm_ae)
history=model_lstm_ae.fit(X_train_, X_train_, 
                          epochs=100, 
                          batch_size=256, 
                          validation_data = (X_test_, X_test_),
                          verbose = 1,
                          callbacks = [early_stopping_monitor, lr_reduce])
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The first layer in a Sequential model must get an `input_shape` or `batch_input_shape` argument.
```

Any suggestions on how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I run your model (inclduing the KerasRegressor and Reshape) with TF2 RC2 on a linux machine. To be sure, please provide some data for your variables. I suppose you just need to adapt your imports.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).